# React Native Navigator with Alert not working

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a test login page. In this page, if user press  `'LOGIN'`
button then the app should show an Alert dialog. If the user chooses `'YES'` in the dialog only then the app should navigate to next page.

**Problem**

When I call navigator on click event of `'YES'` button then nothing is happening. I am sharing my class what am I missing? However, if I call it from button click it works without any issue.

**Code Snippet**

```
import Style from '../Style';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,TextInput,Alert,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,Linking ,ToastAndroid,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { text: 'Search Movies' };
   this.goToHome = this.goToHome.bind(this);
 }

    goToHome() {
    ToastAndroid.show('A pikachu appeared nearby !', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
     this.props.navigator.push({
        name: 'Home',
        title: 'Home',
        openMenu: this.openMenu
     });
  }

  showConfirmationDialog(){
          Alert.alert(
                'FingerPrint Authentication',
                'Would you like to authenticate using fingerprint ?',
                [
                  {text: 'Yes', onPress: () => {ToastAndroid.showWithGravity('Ticket Booked :D',ToastAndroid.SHORT, ToastAndroid.CENTER);}},
                  {text: 'No', onPress: () => { this.goToHome}},
                  {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () =>console.log('Cancelled'), style: 'cancel'},
                ],
                  { cancelable: false }
                  )
                }

  render() {

    return (

      <View style={Style.container}>
      <ScrollView style={Style.plot}>

              <Text style={Style.welcome}>
                 Sign In
                </Text>

               <View style={Style.settings}/>

               <Text style={Style.label}>
              User Name
               </Text>

              <TextInput
                 style={Style.input}
                 onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
                 value={this.state.text}
               />

               <Text style={Style.label}>
              Password
               </Text>

              <TextInput
                 style={Style.input}
                 onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
                 value={this.state.text}
               />

       <View style={Style.buttonContainer}>
         <TouchableOpacity
           onPress= { this.showConfirmationDialog}
           activeOpacity={0.7}
           style={Style.buttonClose}>
           <Text style={Style.buttonText}>Login</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>

    </ScrollView>
    </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Login', () => Login);
```

if I change `onPress= { this.showConfirmationDialog}` to `onPress= { this.goToHome}` in LOGIN button it works but not on OK button of the dialog.

Comment: Does binding showConfirmationDialog help?

Comment: in your "No" text onPress is work or not.?

Comment: binding showConfirmationDialog didn't help; No button show a toast but nothing happens on Yes button.

Comment: Okay then you have to try out to put your Yes button code inside a function and then just call function on Yes Button may be this will sort you out from your error.